# A question about Comparatives

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, comparatives

As I understand it, comparatives compare with something. But which of the following sentences is correct.

> 1. It wasn't busy tonight at the club? can you say next week will be busier?
> 2. It wasn't busy tonight at the club? can you say next week will be busy?

Both are correct right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would say that both are correct. In #1, you're asking whether the club will be busier than not busy at all. In #2, you're asking if the club will be busy, as opposed to not busy. I think they come down to the same thing, and neither is incorrect.

Comment: //It wasn't busy tonight at the club? can you say next week will be busier?// These sentences are contradictory for the intended sense.  It should ideally be, "...not busy tonight...."; will it be busy next week? It should ideally be, "It wasn't busy tonight at the club? Can you say next week will be busy? Thus, the second sentences are more correct.